# Codename One show image only on specific device

Tags: codenameone

I'm coding an app via Codename One. Since the screen of an iPad or other tablet is bigger than a phone's display and that would leave me with a bunch of open space, I was wondering if there is something in Codename One to have an image pop-up on a tablet but that it is not visible on a phone's display.

So is there something like that? How can I use it?

Thank you in advance!

- Nick van Kesteren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Display.isTablet()](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#isTablet--) to adapt the UI for a tablet. Normally you don't do this at the image level but rather at a `Container` level.

E.g. I could do something like this:

```
Form myForm = new Form("My Title", new BorderLayout());

// add the stuff that's always here...


if(Display.getInstance().isTablet()) {
   myForm.add(BorderLayout.EAST, createAdditionalTabletUI());
}
```

You can also enable other things such as [permanent side menu](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/permanent-sidemenu-getAllStyles-scrollbar-and-more.html) to make the UI use the tablet aspects more intelligently.